# I have a syntax and a test code for the syntax but it won't run when i insert the test code

Tags: python

I have a syntax and a test code for the syntax but it won't run when I insert the test code.

Test code:

```
hour,minute,second=Timeconversion(second)
print(hour, "hour", minute, "Minute",second,"second")
```

Test input 10500.
Result 2 hour 55 minute 0 second

This is my code:

```
def Timeconversion(second):
    #lengkapi fungsi berikut
    hour=int(second//3600)
    minute=int((second%3600)//60)
    second=int((second%3600)%60)
    hour, minute, second = Timeconversion(second)

second=int(input()) 
print (hour, "hour", minute, "minute", second, "second")
```

It always errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\No 4.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (hour, "hour", minute, "minute", second, "second")
NameError: name 'hour' is not defined
```

Comment: That's probably the input value. For example, `10500 // 3600 == 2`.

Comment: How is this not throwing a recursion error?

Comment: Presumably the line where you call `Timeconversion` is not supposed to be *inside* the definition of `Timeconversion`.

Comment: Well, you put the line `hour,minute,second=Timeconversion(second)` inside the function for some reason... It should be outside the function, and the function should have `return hour, minute, second` instead...

Comment: @MarkMoretto Because the function is never called.

Comment: There is also `return` statement in your function definition. Moreover, the indented `hour, minute, second =...` seems wrong. Please check again.

Comment: @khelwood The function is called within the function?  The function never returns anything, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MarkMoretto you are right but it is never called **outside of itself**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will work with the following changes:

1. Add return statement for function
2. Remove recursive call
3. Call `hour,minute,second=Timeconversion(second)` before print

```py
def Timeconversion(second):
    #lengkapi fungsi berikut
    hour=int(second//3600)
    minute=int((second%3600)//60)
    second=int((second%3600)%60)
    return hour,minute,second

second=int(input()) 
hour,minute,second=Timeconversion(second)
print (hour, "hour", minute, "minute", second, "second")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.  No recursion and you're unpacking the appropriate time segments.

```
test = 10500
def Timeconversion(second):
    #lengkapi fungsi berikut
    hour=int(second//3600)
    minute=int((second%3600)//60)
    second=int((second%3600)%60)
    return hour, minute, second


hour,minute,second=Timeconversion(test)
print(hour, "hour", minute, "Minute",second,"second")
```